# PrestaShop: non-www URLs redirecting to 404 error page

Tags: redirect, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I am experiencing a weird issue on my PrestaShop website.

When I am opening an URL without WWW on it, it redirects to the WWW page, but displays 404 page.

for example, when I am trying to access `http://mydomain.com/home/contact-us` it takes me to `http://www.mydomain.com/home/contact-us?controller=404`. It should not add `?controller=404` to the end of the url. Why it's doing this and how to fix this issue?

Comment: This problem also occurs if users click on the links from the Google Index.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to manually edit the .htaccess file of your Prestashop website. You can redirect all non-www urls to add www using this code.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Place the code on top of your .htaccess file or within the condition block for checking mod_rewrite

Comment: What if I want the opposite? route www. to non-www?
When I add RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
I get a too much redirects error.

Answer (score 1):

you can set your url under "Preferences > SEO & URLs". you have to change the options "Shop domain" and "SSL domain" there you can set with or without "WWW".

Comment: We need to use the domain with WWW. So, in the "Preferences > SEO & URLs" section, I have set "Shop domain" and "SSL domain" as "www.mydomain.com". But this does not solve the issue.

Comment: I just forgot to add www to the domain in "Shop domain" and this answer helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably cased by not-generated .htaccess file. Go to BackOffice -> Preferences -> SEO & URLs and click [Save]. This will regenerate your .htaccess file.

Comment: No, the .htaccess file is generated by PrestaShop. I have added my rules to it. I even tried to regenerate the .htaccess file again. But this does not solve the issue.

Comment: look at your hosting or .htaccess file, maybe something redirecting to it.